# Two icons in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have an icon in a JLabel as shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to add another icon (e.g. a flag representing a country) between the color icon and the text? For example, I want to add an icon depicting the U.S. flag between the red icon and `US`. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, use nested JLabel with BoxLayout in the container label:

```
JLabel container = new JLabel();
container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
JLabel icon1Label = new JLabel();
JLabel icon2Label = new JLabel();
icon1Label.setIcon(icon1);
icon2Label.setIcon(icon2);
container.add(icon1Label);
container.add(icon2Label);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I also added `container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)))` to add some space between the two icons.

Comment: Does this work with JLabel's horizontal alignment (e.g. `SwingConstants.CENTER`)?

Answer (score 10):

Try [CompoundIcon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/)
Edit: Heisenbug's layout-based solution is the 
trivial answer.

Comment: or nest the containers in a layout.  or add another column in the list just for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I just did this recently - I wanted to be able to combine multiple icons in a single row into a single icon. The way I did it was to go down to the `BufferedImage` level and compose the two images manually into a single image, and then use that as my `JLabel` icon. There are other ways of achieving the same effect, but I didn't want to have to change my UI component hierarchy.

I ended up creating a class that combines multiple images and caches them. I used it like this:

```
ImageIcon icon1 = ...;
ImageIcon icon2 = ...;

ImageIcon labelIcon = new CachedCompositeIcon( icon1, icon2 ).getIcon();
jLabel.setIcon( labelIcon );
```

Here's the source:

```
/** This is a convenience class to handle creating a single composite icon from several icons, and caching the
 *  created icons to eliminate duplicate work. This class is basically used as a key into a map, allowing us to
 *  define both a hashCode and equals in a single place.
 */
public class CachedCompositeIcon
{
    private static final byte ICON_PADDING = 2;
    private static final HashMap<CachedCompositeIcon, ImageIcon> CACHED_ICONS =
            new HashMap<CachedCompositeIcon, ImageIcon>( 4 );

    private final ImageIcon[] m_icons;

    public CachedCompositeIcon(final ImageIcon... icons) {
        m_icons = icons;
    }

    public ImageIcon getIcon() {
        if ( !CACHED_ICONS.containsKey( this ) ) {
            CACHED_ICONS.put( this, lcl_combineIcons() );
        }

        return CACHED_ICONS.get( this );
    }

    /** Generates an icon that is a composition of several icons by appending each icon together with some
     *  padding between them.
     *
     * @return An icon that is the concatenation of all the icons this was constructed with.
     */
    private ImageIcon lcl_combineIcons() {
        // First determine how big our composite icon will be; we need to know how wide & tall to make it.
        int totalWidth = (m_icons.length - 1) * ICON_PADDING; // Take into account the padding between icons
        int minHeight  = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_icons.length; ++i ) {
            totalWidth += m_icons[i].getIconWidth();
            if ( m_icons[i].getIconHeight() > minHeight ) {
                minHeight = m_icons[i].getIconHeight();
            }
        }

        // Create an image big enough and acquire the image canvas to draw on
        final BufferedImage compositeImage = new BufferedImage( totalWidth, minHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        final Graphics      graphics       = compositeImage.createGraphics();

        // Iterate over the icons, painting each icon and adding some padding space between them
        int x = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_icons.length; ++i ) {
            final ImageIcon icon = m_icons[ i ];
            graphics.drawImage( icon.getImage(), x, 0, null );
            x += icon.getIconWidth() + ICON_PADDING;
        }

        return new ImageIcon( compositeImage );
    }

    /** Generates a hash that takes into account the number of icons this composition includes and the hash &
     *  order of those icons.
     *
     * @return A hash code.
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int weakHash = m_icons.length;
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_icons.length; ++i ) {
            weakHash += m_icons[i].hashCode() * (i + 1);
        }
        return weakHash;
    }

    /** Two instances are equal if and only if they include the same icons and they're in the same order.
     *
     * @param obj An object to check for equality with this.
     *
     * @return true if the two objects are equal, false otherwise.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if ( !(obj instanceof CachedCompositeIcon) ) {
            return false;
        }

        final CachedCompositeIcon other = (CachedCompositeIcon) obj;
        if ( m_icons.length != other.m_icons.length ) {
            return false;
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < m_icons.length; ++i ) {
            if ( m_icons[i].hashCode() != other.m_icons[i].hashCode() ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is pretty possible, JLabel is Swing JComponent and you can add any JComponent to the another JComponent, that's same for JLabel

```
label.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
label.add(myIcon1);
label.add(myIcon2);
```

if you add f.e. JPanel to the JLabel then don't forget to `setOpaque(false);`